# FFmpeg subtitle filter set start time

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, subtitle

I am trying to burn-in subtitles for a shorter section of a video, but using the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1) filter always starts from the beginning of the subtitle stream, not at the specified start time, even when copying from the same video.

So for example if I start an encode 10 minutes in to a film, the video will properly be set from there, but the subtitles will start from the beginning (10 minute offset in this case).

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 600.0 -to 660.0 -i movie.mkv -filter_complex "[0:0]subtitles='movie.mkv':si=1[v]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx265 -crf 22 output.mkv
```

This is not a problem when using picture based subtitles and the overlay filter, such as:

```
-filter_complex "[0:0][0:2]overlay[v]"
```

It seems to only affect text based subtitles. I don't know if this is just not possible and will require another solution, or if I am approaching it wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I was using "fast seek" time, aka setting it before the input, which does not seem to be compatible with the `subtitle` filter. Which means the `-ss` and `-to` need to be moved after the input `-i movie.mkv`

```
ffmpeg -y  -i movie.mkv -ss 600.0 -to 660.0 -filter_complex "[0:0]subtitles='movie.mkv':si=1[v]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx265 -crf 22 output.mkv
```